# Increased Error with more Training Data for a Neural Network in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have a question regarding the Matlab NN toolbox. As a part of research project I decided to create a Matlab script that uses the NN toolbox for some fitting solutions.

I have a data stream that is being loaded to my system. The Input data consists of 5 input channels and 1 output channel. I train my data on on this configurations for a while and try to fit the the output (for a certain period of time) as new data streams in. I retrain my network constantly to keep it updated.

So far everything works fine, but after a certain period of time the results get bad and do not represent the desired output. I really can't explain why this happens, but i could imagine that there must be some kind of memory issue, since as the data set is still small, everything is ok.

Only when it gets bigger the quality of the simulation drops down. Is there something as a memory which gets full, or is the bad sim just a result of the huge data sets? I'm a beginner with this tool and will really appreciate your feedback. Best Regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a potentially interesting question, but I don't think you have given nearly enough information about the NN setup and the incoming data for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your comment. The NN setup configuration is as follows: 1 Neuron, Training function: trainingbr, 0.7/0.15/0.15. The data is a machine data stream, 5 input channels, 1 output as i mentioned in the previous post. I  train on the data for 1 hour of data then i simulated the next hour. I then train on 2 hours of data and simulate the 3rd hour and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate on your method of retraining with new data. Do you run further iterations? What do you consider as "time"? Do you mean epochs?

At a first glance, assuming time means epochs, I would say that you're overfitting the data. Neural Networks are supposed to be trained for a limited number of epochs with [early stopping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_stopping). You could try regularization, different gradient descent methods (if you're using a GD method), GD momentum. Also depending on the values of your first few training datasets, you may have trained your data using an incorrect normalization range. You should check these issues out if my assumptions are correct.

Comment: Hi, with time a mean train on 1 hour of data (e.g. 1Hz Data - 3600 data rows.) After this 1 hr of training (3600 points) i simulate the next hour (next 3600 points). After the second hour has passed, i use available 2 hrs of data (7200 lines), retrain the network and simulate the 3rd hour. this procedure is repeated for the complete range of my data. the problem is that everything work fine until a certain stage and then the quality rapidly drops. I have described the setup of my NN above.

Comment: @mitCo I see. There could be multiple issues so I think saying it's the memory is a bit farfetched.

Perhaps it would be useful to either subsample the data by taking take less data from each source (e.g. 50% of the first hour and 50% of the second hour). I do this with some of my data for SVM training.

Another thing to try is to change your architecture. Consider expanding your architecture to include more neurons. More neurons allow you to cover more variant data, but again keep in mind the issue about overtraining

Comment: At the end of the day, if there is a change in the model, you might not be able to model this change and may need more layers.